# MonoGame - how to share my game with others?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, monogame

I wrote game in MonoGame. It was compiled in .NET 4.5. I copied Release folder and gave it to my friend but wasn't able to run it. He has installed .NET 4.5 but he doesn't have XNA or MonoGame. Should I include some extra files to it?

Answer (score 1):

To release a game with MonoGame you must provide the correct DLL files for the platform. Assuming that he is running Windows, you should include the following for a WindowsGL MonoGame game

- MonoGame.Framework.dll
- OpenTk.dll
- any other dlls that you are using

Essentially (keep this in mind for other platforms such as WindowsDX (DirectX), Linux, and Mac), just include the DLL files that you used to build the project with, along with the executable in a folder, as well as any other resources that you included already.

Comment: @MickyDuncan The DX dlls that you embed are for SharpDX, the bindings between the system DX runtime that is required and C#. FYI.

Comment: MonoGame.Framework.dll was already included. I didn't use OpenTk, so I think it is not needed

Comment: @petros Could you include the specific error that was given? If you do not include OpenTk (and maybe even if you do), they should have the correct .NET version installed as well as OpenAL for sound.

Comment: @petros I have a feeling that this could be an issue with your code rather than a distribution problem. Try asking a question on the MonoGame github issues page https://github.com/mono/MonoGame